# Iterating through string for patterns?

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm doing a python practice problem where I have to distinguish patterns. For example, one pattern is where I have to count the "oo"'s surrounded by several x's.

```
line = "xooxxxxooxxxxoxoxxxxoxoxxxxxxxoxoxxoooxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

The "oo"'s surrounded by x's is only one of the couple other patterns. I tried using a for loop but it's embarrassingly not working. Is there a way I can go through a string to pick up certain patterns to add to a count variable? If I learn how to do it for this one, I'm sure I can find the other patterns for this practice. :)
Thanks!

and I tried

```
for "oo" in line:
    count += 1
```

but it doesn't work. Really bad with loops, sorry.
The expected output is the count for this pattern: 2 o's surrounded by x's

Comment: Show us what you have so far.  code which doesn't work is nothing to be embarrassed about -- rather it's an opportunity for us to see what you don't understand yet and help you to actually figure out what is going on in your program.  Also, you should mention what the expected output is.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have a literal (`"oo"`) where you need a variable in order for your loop to work:

```
for "oo" in line:
#   ^literal not allowed here
```

In order to do something like this with a loop, you probably want to loop over the *indices*, inspecting a portion of the string and seeing if it matches a particular substring:

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(line)):
    if line[i:i+4] == 'xoox':
       count += 1
```

Note that doing it this way is definitely not "pythonic".  A pythonic solution would be:

```
line.count('xoox')  #  Batteries included :-)
```

Comment: I seem to always be so slow when answering questions; but nice answer :)

Comment: @Haidro -- Give it time.  You'll get the hang of it and you'll start answering faster.  Sometimes I "cheat" a little by posting the minimal correct answer that I can and then editing like crazy for the next 5 minutes to turn it into something useful ...

Comment: Hah, thanks :). I see your name a lot and you're very experienced with python

Comment: @Haidro -- I learned most of it in the past 12 months hanging around here answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should provide a `SyntaxError`, as you `can't assign to literal`. You're expecting to loop through all the `'oo's` in the string, but alas this isn't what happening, or what should happen.

What you were probably thinking of is to loop through the string and see how many 'oo's there are, which can't be done in this case.

There's a great built-in function called `count()` which... counts. How you use it is:

```
yourstring.count(str) # str here is what you want to count, 
                      # yourstring is where you are counting
```

It returns an integer, so this is the code you want:

```
>>> line = "xooxxxxooxxxxoxoxxxxoxoxxxxxxxoxoxxoooxxxxxxxxxxxx"
>>> line.count('oo')
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Without just flat out giving you the answer the `split` function may be of use to you.... http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#splitting-strings

```
test = "xxxxooxxxxoooxxxx"
test.split("oo")
```

that code returns `['xxxx', 'xxxx', 'oxxxx']`

Hope that helps. In other words, if you have consecutive strings that end in 'x', and the other begins with 'x' you have an occurrence to count.

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions, to answer to your demand:

> I tried using a for loop but it's embarrassingly not working. Is
>   there a way I can go through a string to pick up certain patterns to
>   add to a count variable? If I learn how to do it for this one, I'm
>   sure I can find the other patterns for this practice.

.

## solution 1

```
line = "Bxooxxx xoox  xxoxoxxxoxoxxxox#xoooxxoox"
print line,'\n'

def explore(X):
    it = iter(X)
    prec = it.next()
    print 'prec  ch1  next  next'
    for ch in it:
        print ' %r  %r' % (prec,ch),
        if (prec,ch)==('x','o'):
            prec = it.next()
            print ' %r' % prec,
            if prec=='o':
                prec = it.next()
                if prec =='x':
                    print '  %r    OK !!' % prec
                    yield 1
                else:
                    print '  %r   not good' % prec
            else:
                print '  stop'
        else:
            print
            prec = ch
print sum(explore(line))
```

result

```
Bxooxxx xoox  xxoxoxxxoxoxxxox#xoooxxoox 

prec  ch1  next  next
 'B'  'x'
 'x'  'o'  'o'   'x'    OK !!
 'x'  'x'
 'x'  'x'
 'x'  ' '
 ' '  'x'
 'x'  'o'  'o'   'x'    OK !!
 'x'  ' '
 ' '  ' '
 ' '  'x'
 'x'  'x'
 'x'  'o'  'x'   stop
 'x'  'o'  'x'   stop
 'x'  'x'
 'x'  'x'
 'x'  'o'  'x'   stop
 'x'  'o'  'x'   stop
 'x'  'x'
 'x'  'x'
 'x'  'o'  'x'   stop
 'x'  '#'
 '#'  'x'
 'x'  'o'  'o'   'o'   not good
 'o'  'x'
 'x'  'x'
 'x'  'o'  'o'   'x'    OK !!
3
```

---

## solution 2

```
line = "Bxooxxx xoox  xxoxoxxxoxoxxxox#xoooxxoox"
print line,'\n'

def expl(X):
    it4 = iter(X)
    it4.next();it4.next();it4.next()
    it3 = iter(X)
    it3.next();it3.next()
    it2 = iter(X)
    it2.next()
    it1 = iter(X)
    for a in it4:
        if (it1.next(),it2.next(),it3.next(),a)==('x','o','o','x'):
            yield 1

print sum(expl(line))
```

result

```
Bxooxxx xoox  xxoxoxxxoxoxxxox#xoooxxoox 

3
```

---

## solution 3

```
line = "Bxooxxx xoox  xxoxoxxxoxoxxxox#xoooxxoox"
print line,'\n'

import re
reg = re.compile('(?<=x)oox')
print len(reg.findall(line))
```

result

```
Bxooxxx xoox  xxoxoxxxoxoxxxox#xoooxxoox 

3
```

.

So, think to iterators and generators